# MYSQL Subquery -

Tags: mysql

created this query but all the customers in the table are not showing up, i want all customers to show in the query even with any null values.there are 26 customers in the customer table but only 12 show when i run the query.

```
SELECT c.CID, CONCAT(c.FirstName, ' ', c.LastName) AS 'Customer Name', 
            c.Email, o.OrderDate, o.OrderStatus, o.DeliveryDate, a.AppetizerName, o.AppetizerQuantity, 
            p.PizzaName, p.PizzaSize, o.PizzaQuantity, pa.PastaName, o.PastaQuantity, 
            s.SandwichName, o.SandwichQuantity, d.DessertName, o.DessertQuantity, 
            dr.DrinkName, o.DrinksQuantity, o.TotalPrice 
            FROM 
        customer AS c 
            JOIN 
        orders AS o ON c.CID = o.CID 
            INNER JOIN 
        appetizer AS a ON a.AppetizerID = o.AppetizerID 
            INNER JOIN 
        pizza AS p ON p.PizzaID = o.PizzaID 
            INNER JOIN 
        pasta AS pa ON pa.PastaID = o.PastaID 
            INNER JOIN 
        sandwiches AS s ON s.SandwichID = o.SandwichID 
            INNER JOIN 
        dessert AS d ON d.DessertID = o.DessertID 
            INNER JOIN 
        drinks AS dr ON dr.DrinkID = o.DrinkID
        GROUP BY c.FirstName, c.LastName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're using inner joins. These drop null values. If you replace each of your inner joins with left joins, your query should return all 26 customers.